# Oracle SQL Query - zero result even if the criteria of the query are correct

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm facing a strange probleme with my Oracle SQL Query, my query looks like :

```
select * 
from user e 
where  e.year= 2014 and e.user =305 and e.usercat =22 and e.datereg= '25/07/2014'
```

When a select the whole content, I can find this specific user, but once I add the column **datereg** to the query, it doesn't give me any result (0 row)!!

I have a problem with the value of the **datereg** column only for this user, and no probleme with other users (when i change the **datereg** value).

Any idea please ?

Comment: Can you show the records from the table using `select * from user e where  e.year= 2014 and e.user =305 and e.usercat =22`? Is the `datereq` column a date?

Comment: Yes - what data type is the column `datereq`? This is a critical piece of information.

Comment: @ElectricLlama it's a "Date"

Comment: `e.datereg= '25/07/2014'` compares a `date` with a string literal and thus implicit data type conversion takes place. Never ever rely on implicit data type conversion! Use a proper date literal instead (e.g. ANSI date literals or by using `to_date()`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in my case, do you think "to_date" is better for and valid for the whole column (even if i dont have any problem with other values?)

Comment: Always use `to_date()` when specifying date constants with a format mask that is independent of the language, so no month *names* in there.  You should also read Gordon's answer about the time part of an Oracle `date` column

Answer (score 3):

I assume datereg is of type date.

So the criteria should be:

```
e.datereg = to_date('25/07/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

if datereg also has a time portion try

```
trunc(e.datereg) = to_date('25/07/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

which brings me to the same solution as Gordon :)

Comment: but why it works with other values like '26/07/2014' !! and why I have to use to_date function ?

Comment: if it works with with 26 and not with 25 then there is something else going on. I've seen to many unpredicted results when letting the system detect a date format. So I like to force things a little bit.

Comment: Maybe because i use "sysdate" function to insert this row ?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me !!

Answer (score 2):

This would typically happen when you have a time component.  Try changing the logic to:

```
trunc(e.datereg) = '25/07/2014'
```

EDIT:

Your version fails because a date with a time is not equal to a date without a time.  This happens all the time with comparisons using `sysdate`, which has a time component.

Use `to_date()` for the date constant if you need.  I would always use ISO standard formats for this:

```
trunc(e.datereg) = to_date('2014-07-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You can also use the default date format:

```
trunc(e.datereg) = '25-07-2014'
```

However, this can be influenced by internationalization settings.

EDIT II:

By default, I mean the "default" value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.  It is better to do the conversions explicitly.  Oracle is well [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) on the use of date constants.  I think I now prefer:

```
trunc(e.datereg) = DATE '2014-07-25'
```

Comment: It works, but could you please give us a clear explanation of the problem ? Thanks

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised this works without an explicit call to `to_date()` - is this a special sort of date literal that's guaranteed to work regardless of NLS settings?

Comment: In fact, I just checked - this will fail with American NLS settings (ORA-01843: not a valid month)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt then, what's the best solution?

Comment: Use an explicit `to_date()` call (as suggested by Conffusion), and if your date contains a time component, add a `trunc()`, as suggested by Gordon Linoff.

Comment: `trunc(e.datereg) = '25-07-2014'` is rather dangerous (because of the NLS settings you mentioned) - I would not include that in an answer - especially not in an answer to someone who apparently did not understand the difference between a "real" date value and a character literal.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I think the problem is the time component on the date.  Oracle is rather confusing, because it often prints out dates without the time component, making it look like the comparisons are failing.

Comment: Yes I know that, but relying on implicit data type conversion is still a bad habit (and one that is begging for problems)

Comment: Exactly, i used "sysdate" function. i think, it's better to usually use trunc function ?

Comment: @MehdiBoussarhane . . . For your purposes, with this query, the `trunc()` function is a fine solution.

Comment: Any particular reason this keeps getting downvotes?  The OP has admitted that the time component was the problem.

Comment: There is no default date format in Oracle, though you can use a date literal and you're suggesting that the OP use implicit conversion, which will be wrong for the vast majority of people who use this answer in the future, and as you don't know the OPs NLS_DATE_FORMAT potentially for the OP as well.

Comment: @Ben What's the solution in your opinion ?

Comment: Gordon's given you the solution @Mehdi, there's just extra stuff that could change on a session-by-session basis. Convert explicitly to a date and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Ben The problem that I'm using this Query in Java application, I have to use the correct solution, because i will not have to change it everytime. This is why I have to choose the correct answer and the correct function. And i will use "trunc(e.datereg) = to_date('2014-07-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD') " is better i guess ?

Comment: @MehdiBoussarhane . . . That is a very reasonable solution.